# Asymptotic distribution for non differentiable functions of estimators

Tags: probability-theory, derivatives

is there kind of a standard tool to derive the distribution of $f(\theta)$ if f is non differentiable (so no Delta Method available) and $\theta$ is asymptotically normal distributed?
Thanks a lot!